# I cannot open an Xpage template?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to use templates for my development (I have always in the past) but it seems that I cannot open a template in an Xpage. When I try I get this error:

"Xpages cannot proccess the Application launch page"

Comment: A .ntf template? You can not run XPages in a .ntf file.

Comment: Ask IBM. So create a .nsf from your template (or rename the file extension to .nsf)

Comment: Remember that a .nsf can be a template too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPages application [does not work](http://lotusandjava.blogspot.sk/2012/02/xpages-does-not-run-in-ntf.html) from template file with .NTF extension. As mentioned by Per Henrik, you can use .NSF file and inherit from it.